# Height of peaks with find_peaks and prominence parameter is consequently too high

Tags: python, plot

I've plotted `csvelocity_detrend` and the peaks that `find_peaks` found:

[image: I've plotted csvelocity_detrend and the peaks that find_peaks found]

It seems like the height of my peaks are consequently too high.

Here's my code:

```
    # Opening and reader CSV file with pandas
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        data = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=",", decimal=".")

    # Assigning arrays to names
    _, time, az, ay, ax = (
        data["time"],
        data["seconds_elapsed"],
        data["z"],
        data["y"],
        data["x"],
    )

...

    csvelocity = np.cumsum(vect)
    csvelocity_detrend = detrend(csvelocity)
    velpeaks, velprom = find_peaks(csvelocity_detrend, prominence=100)
    csposition = np.cumsum(csvelocity_detrend)
    csposition_detrend = detrend(csposition)
    pospeaks, posprom = find_peaks(csposition_detrend, prominence=3000)

...

    plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
    plt.title(f"Velocity", fontsize=20)
    plt.plot(
        # time, csvelocity,
        time, csvelocity_detrend,
        time[velpeaks], (velprom["prominences"]), "o",
        time, zero, "black",

    )
    plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
    plt.title(f"Position", fontsize=20)
    plt.plot(
        # time, csposition,
        time, csposition_detrend,
        time[pospeaks], posprom["prominences"], "o",
        time, zero, "black",
    )
```

Result of print(posprom) :

```
{'prominences': array([6519.38545517, 5415.92323387, 4788.15834837, 4182.40803139,
       6746.76815107, 4794.75025253, 5817.89364251, 4476.53716508]), 'left_bases': array([ 451,  943, 1371, 1371, ,  943, 1371, 1371, 1371, 2281, 2682, 3087], dtype=int64), 'right_bases': array([1371, 1371, 1603, 1918, 2682, 2682, 3087, 3314], dtype=int64)}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. The reason I use prominence is because I have multiple signals that don't have the same height. They range from 60 to 100, while some lower peaks in signals with biggen amplitudes also might reach 60.

I tried using left_bases and right_bases parameters as well but both dont seem accurate.